# log4net configuration for connectionType version and public key for .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, sql-server, configuration, visual-studio-2012, log4net

I am using the latest version of `log4net`.  Just a couple of questions regarding the connectionType version and public key values.

The sample that you get on the log4net website looks like this:

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

I have seen on SO the following:

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2.  How do I know what version I will need to use and what will be the public key be (both seem to be the same for the 2 different versions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Framework 4.5 still uses `4.0.0.0` for System.Data.SqlClient. If you add the reference to any project and view the properties, you can see the details, including the path, which is;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll
```

The public key will be the same for all versions.

Answer (score 11):

Add `System.Data` to your project references (it already should be there). Select it and look to the properties window. You need `Version` property (should be `4.0.0.0`). Set that version to your connection type value in configuration. Public key should stay the same:

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```